# Whats the best way to migrate a zookeeper ensemble of 3?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, high-availability

I have a ZK ensemble of 3 nodes.

I need to move each to a different server.

Whats the best way to achieve this while achieving 0 downtime?

An approach that temporary requires increasing the ensemble size would work too. Achieving 0 downtime is the main goal.

Answer (score 4):

have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/miketheman/6057930

1. Add two more nodes on the new servers
2. let them sync, then add them to the existing configs
3. Restart the followers
4. Kill the remaining Master and deploy the 3. ZK on the new server
5. kill the two ZK on the wrong servers

Comment: assuming 3 nodes ABC and new nodes DE: after step 3 and restarting follower node C, CDE will have majority and if D is elected leader, he will say cluster has no data.

Comment: Have you tested it? If I'm not completely wrong, D & E should sync their data, when you add them to the ensemble.